# pandas dataframe indexing within loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this has been asked somewhere but I can't find it.. so apologies.

I have a dataframe: df and I want to say for column A and rows 0 to 10, give the values of x

but I need to do this in a loop.

I've used this code in my loop but it doesn't work. I know I need to use loc but can't see how to do columns and rows indexing

```
colname='A'
df[colname][:10]=x
```

This does work but it brings up that red box 100's of times, saying it's not a good way of doing it...

*See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
C:\Users\FSC05\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:18: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame*

Thanks in advance for your help.

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Pandas, you should look to *avoid* Python-level loops. Here, you can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for integer positional indexing:

```
x = df.iloc[:10, df.columns.get_loc('A')]
```

`iloc` can be used to set as well as retrieve values:

```
x = 5
df.iloc[:10, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = x
```

This assumes, as should generally be the case, your column labels are unique.

Comment: thanks for this. I'm really trying to get my head around indexing. Is anyone able to explain why my method didn't work? and the one above does?

Comment: Firstly, it's not clear what `x` is in your code. Secondly, chained indexing is explicitly discouraged in the docs (the link you've included), so *never* use syntax `df[...][...]`. Thirdly, you are assigning `x` to some kind of slice, but you want to do it the *other way round*, i.e. assign some result to a variable `x`.

Comment: ok. x is just a random number. So if I have a time series column 0,0,0,4,5,4 I'd like to change the first 2 rows to x, so the output would be x,x,0,4,5,4

Comment: @fred.Schwartz, Got it, `iloc` can be used to set *and* retrieve values, have updated to clarify.